# Cannot update FreeBSD Freshports Plexpass

Tags: linux, freebsd, ports, pkg-config, plex

I used to update my port of plexpass in FreeBSD by stopping my jail, and entering the following:

```
pkg update && pkg upgrade
portsnap fetch update
pkg upgrade plexmediaserver-plexpass
pkg install plexmediaserver-plexpass
```

This use to work just fine, but at some point along the way the port stopped updating. I have since updated my FreeNAS installation to v11 (stable), but this did not help. I have tried forcing pkg update and pkg upgrade, but this just reports back that the packages are all up-to-date.

I am currently running v1.3.3.3148 of plexpass, but according to freshports, the newest version is v1.8.0.4109.

Here is the link for the freshports page:
    https://www.freshports.org/multimedia/plexmediaserver-plexpass/

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of digging I found an answer. Because my jails was from a very old version of FreeNAS (BSD), the template was out of date and not able to be updated. This is a known issue and there are several bugs reported to FreeNAS and FreeBSD. I found one forum post that helped discover the issue but was not able to resolve the problems.

I decided to create a new jail, install my packages from scratch and move the metadata over. After dealing with some permission issues with the moved metadata, I got everything working correctly. Packages are now updating, plexpass is working and all my metadata is in tact. Here is the post that helped me find my issue:

https://forums.freenas.org/index.php?threads/keeping-the-jails-up-to-date.20062/

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to get all the source ports when using `pkg`, try to update this file `/etc/pkg/FreeBSD.conf` With something like this:

```
FreeBSD: {
  url: "pkg+http://pkg.FreeBSD.org/${ABI}/latest",
  mirror_type: "srv",
  signature_type: "fingerprints",
  fingerprints: "/usr/share/keys/pkg",
  enabled: yes
}
```

Notice the line:

```
url: "pkg+http://pkg.FreeBSD.org/${ABI}/latest"
```

That indicates to install the latest packages.

You can read more about it here: https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?pkg(7), especially check the Configuration section.

Comment: I checked this config file and this was already how the config file was setup. I still have the same issue when I try to run "pkg update -f" or "pkg upgrade -f".

Any other thoughts?

Comment: This are the current versions `plexmediaserver-1.7.5.4035`   and `plexmediaserver-plexpass-1.8.0.4109` try `pkg install plexmediaserver-plexpass`

Comment: I have tried installing it with that command... here is what I get:

_Updating FreeBSD repository catalogue...
FreeBSD repository is up-to-date.
All repositories are up-to-date.
Checking integrity... done (0 conflicting)
The most recent version of packages are already installed_

Comment: If I try running `pkg upgrade -f`, then I get this:

_Updating FreeBSD repository catalogue...
FreeBSD repository is up-to-date.
All repositories are up-to-date.
Checking for upgrades (38 candidates): 100%
Processing candidates (38 candidates): 100%
Checking integrity... done (0 conflicting)
The following 38 package(s) will be affected (of 0 checked):

Installed packages to be REINSTALLED:

        plexmediaserver-plexpass-1.3.3.3148

Number of packages to be reinstalled: 38

Proceed with this action? [y/N]:_


FreeBSD thinks the repositories are up-to-date... Any thoughts?

Comment: try a `pkg info plexmediaserver-plexpass` and check what Repository is been used maybe is not using the `latest`

Comment: Here is what is said for the repository:

`repo_type: binary`
`repository: FreeBSD`

The version number is still listed as v1.3.3.3148.

From my understanding, I should using the official FreeBSD repository... which it is... any thoughts?